# Cómo puedo calcular el perimetro de una figura pintada en un datagridview? es una figura tipo pixelart

Tags: c#, windows-forms

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        //
        // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        //
        // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
        //
    }
    void DataGridView1CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor == Color.Red) 
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = null;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "1";
        }
    }
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text==""||textBox2.Text=="") 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hay un campo vacio");
        }
        else
        {
        int x,y;
        x=int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        y=int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        DataGridViewColumn cuadcolu;

        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) 
        {
            cuadcolu=new DataGridViewColumn(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell());
            cuadcolu.Width=25;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cuadcolu);
        }
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x);
        }

    }
    void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x,y,n=0,p,r=0,c=0,ren=0,col=0;
        x=int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        y=int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) 
            {
                if (dataGridView1[j,i].Value!=null) 
                {
                    n++;
                    for (int k = 0; k < x; k++) 
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1[j,k].Value!=null) 
                        {
                            r--;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    ren=(2*r)-2;
                    for (int k = 0; k < y; k++) 
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1[k,i].Value!=null) 
                        {
                            c--;
                        }

                    }
                    col=(2*c)-2;

                }
            }
        }
        p=(4*n)+ren+col;
        MessageBox.Show(p.ToString());
    }
}
}
```

Tengo un datagridview y en ese datagridview puedo generar x numero de columnas y renglones etc, al dar un click en una celda me lo pinta de un color, y así puedo "pintar" una figura tipo pixelart (hasta aqui tengo hecho) mi problema es de que a esa figura que genero le tengo que calcular el perimetro y no sé como puedo hacerlo, he buscado pero nada viene relacionado a esto, agradecería bastante la ayuda.

Comment: Agrega el código de como guardas las posiciones de los objetos  pintados o como piensas calcular el perímetro ya sea con listas o una matriz.

Comment: @bercklynCarlosviza el objeto pintado lo convierto en 1 y ahí sé que está pintado

Comment: Tengo maso menos la solución en seudocodigo. Solo por curiosidad ¿Cuanto valdría el lado de un cuadrado?

Comment: @bercklynCarlosviza Umm 1, cada celda tiene 4 lados, pero si solo un lado sobre sale de la figura (ejemplo celda (10,3)) solo se toma en cuenta ese, o en  la celda 9,3 se toma en cuenta 2 lados, uno vertical y uno horizontal, me explico?

Comment: En un rato te brindo  una posible solución y algunas mejoras en tu código.

Comment: muchísimas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: En un rato adjunto el código para que veas maso menos la funcionalidad.

Comment: ya publique  mi respuesta. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda viejo! de verdad! solo tengo una pregunta para qué es la condición "if (rows == 0 || columns == 0)"??

Comment: Solo es una validación adicional para impedir el calculo cuando uno de los campos sea 0. Si mi respuesta fue de ayuda marcala como la mejor. Suerte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para calcular tu perímetro deberás tener varias restricciones acerca de tu figura una de ellas seria validar que no tenga espacios internos en blanco y si te permite tenerlos seria validar el calculo de tu perímetro. Por otro lado si haces pruebas te permite dibujar figuras en donde los bloques estén de forma diagonal lo cual no considero que sea un figura valida.

## Solución

Para calcular el perímetro tendrás que recorrer  por completo cada cuadrante de tu Datagrdview para preguntar primero si es o no un cuadrado pintado. De ser uno validar   en los lados izquierda, derecha , arriba y abajo si no esta pintado. Debes tener en cuenta  los casos especiales  según su posición  es decir si estas en la posición  columna =0 y fila =0 no deberás preguntar  si hay uno arriba o en el lado izquierdo por que de hacerlo te lanzara error del tipo fuera de rango.
Cuando se cumpla que no este pintado en el lado  que buscas incrementaras un contador. Al final multiplicaras dicho contador por el valor de un lado del cuadrante.

Por ultimo te recomiendo que cuando crees el nuevo Datagridview guardes los valores con los cuales lo creas en variables declaradas fuera de tu función, ya que si cambias los textbox  y calculas el perímetro te lanzara error.

```
    int rows = 0;
    int columns = 0;
```

Funcion

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int prm = 0;
        int lado = 5;
        if (rows == 0 || columns == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show( "No se puede calcular perimetro" );
        }
        else
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1[r, c].Value != null) // cuadrante pintado
                    {
                        //validacion de lado izquierdo
                        if (r == 0) //si es cero no cuento el lado izquierdo
                            prm++;
                        else
                        {
                            if (dataGridView1[r - 1, c].Value == null)
                                prm++;
                        }

                        //validacion lado derecho
                        if (r == rows - 1) // si es el ultimo no cuento el lado derecho
                            prm++;
                        else
                        {
                            if (dataGridView1[r + 1, c].Value == null)
                                prm++;
                        }

                        //validacion arriba
                        if (c == 0) // no cuento al de arriba
                            prm++;
                        else
                        {
                            if (dataGridView1[r, c - 1].Value == null)
                                prm++;
                        }

                        //validacion abajo
                        if (c == columns - 1) // no cuento al de abajo
                            prm++;
                        else
                        {
                            if (dataGridView1[r, c + 1].Value == null)
                                prm++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // al final multiplico los lados disponibles  por el valor de cada lado
            prm = prm * lado;

            // aqui puedes agregar un messagebox o cambiar el texto de un label
        }
    }
```